# Openapi generator: is it possible to exclude some headers from auto generated code parameters?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to support some "infrastructural" headers and use them to describe my api but, in the generation phase, I don't want those headers to show up as parameters in the code.
I will take care of them by using specific means such as interceptors.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have similar problem. Still can't find any answer.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had to write a custom mustache template and define a vendor extension of mine. Here's the snippet that could help:

```
            {{#vendorExtensions.x-custom}}
            ,@ApiImplicitParam(name = "param", value = "First param", required=false, dataType = "Integer", paramType = "header")
        {{/vendorExtensions.x-custom}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In my case, I created a script that modified my OpenAPI spec (by excluding certain request parameters). And then I proceed normally with openapi generator.